# To prove mean value property for real part of holomorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

The mean-value property for holomorphic functions states that if $f$ is holomorphic in an open disc centered at $z_{0}$ of radius $R$, then
$$f(z_{0}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(z_{0} + re^{i\theta})\, d\theta$$
for any $0 < r < R$.

I want to prove this for $u= Re(f)$ 
means I want to prove that
$$u(z_{0}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}u(z_{0} + re^{i\theta})\, d\theta$$
for any $0 < r < R$.

I just know that u is harmonic whenever f is holomorphic.

Also if I want to prove the mean value property for holomorphic function f then
I know that if $f$ is holomorphic in an open disc centered at $z_{0}$ of radius $R$, then it has power series expansion $f(z)=\sum a_n (z-z_0)^n$

using Cauchy Integral formula we have 
$a_n =\frac{1}{2\pi r^n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(z_{0} + re^{i\theta})e^{-in\theta}, d\theta$

If I substitut $z=z_0+re^{i\theta}$ in $f(z)$ then I get
$f(z_0+re^{i\theta})= \sum \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}u(z_{0} + re^{i\theta})\, d\theta$.
Please anyone correct me why I am getting $f(z_0+re^{-i\theta})$ instead of $f(z_0=$?

Comment: Just take the real part of both sides of the first equation in the OP.

Comment: Note that for analytic functions it reduces to showing it for $z^n$ and use linearity. If $f$ is  only known to be holomorphic, we can use the Cauchy integral formula for showing  it is analytic

Comment: Yes I agree but what about the proof for holomorphic function f? How can I prove the mean value property for holomorphic functions?